# Не работают стили при добавлении новых input

Tags: javascript, html, css, input

[image: скрин как выглядит сейчас]

есть плагин который изменяет стили input при добавлении класса styler. но при добавлении новых сертификатов стили не работают. Нужно чтобы новые элементы отображались как, тот который выше.

```js
unction add_images(id) 
{
    var node = document.getElementById(id),
    newNode = document.createElement('div');
    newNode.innerHTML = '<input type="file" class="styler" name="certificate[]" accept="image/*" id="item_'+idme+'"> <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="del_image('+idme+'); return false;">удалить</a>';
    node.appendChild(newNode);
 idme++;       
    return newNode;
setTimeout(function() {
      $('file').trigger('refresh');
    }, 1);     
}
```

Прикладываю код скрипта отвечающего за добавление нового inputa. 
Страница на которой можно увидеть проблему:  [market.maiso](http://market.maiso.ru)
зайдите в модальное окно **регистрации как продавца и прокрутите вниз**

Answer (score 1):

Вероятно это происходит потому, что класс styler нигде не описан. По крайней мере я не нашел правил для класса styler.

Еще одна возможная причина: по клику добавляется код, который совершенно не похож на исходный.

[image: Вставляемый инпут отличается от исходного]

Answer (score 1):

$('file').trigger('refresh'); - где находится селектор 'file' и зачем обновлять элемент, если ты не подключаешь плагин styler?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Попробуй так $('#images [type=file]').styler();

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
unction add_images(id) 
{
    var node = document.getElementById(id),
    newNode = document.createElement('div');
    newNode.innerHTML = '<input type="file" class="styler" name="certificate[]" accept="image/*" id="item_'+idme+'"> <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="del_image('+idme+'); return false;">удалить</a>';
    node.appendChild(newNode);
    idme++;       
    return newNode;
    setTimeout(function() {
      $('#images [type=file]').styler().trigger('refresh');
      //$('file').trigger('refresh');
    }, 1);     
}
```